# viewContext is not getting saved in the database (app.sqlite)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistence

I created a app to save the details of a student, using NSPersistanceContainer and while I'm getting the data from JSON and saving to db, at that time I'm getting fetch results count > 0. If I restarted the app the fetch result count returns 0.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Students_dev")

    let storeURL = try! FileManager
        .default
        .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent("Students_dev.sqlite")
    print("URL :",storeURL)

    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
    storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext (context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
   
   persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (context) in
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The context is not empty while I'm saving to db, when I check the sqlite file the table is empty. Didn't get what's is missing from my side.

**No data is being get inserted into SQL file**
[image: screenshot of sql log]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was on saveContext function, the context is not getting saved into the core-data  "**persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask**", when i removed it it works fine.

Code

```
func saveContext (context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I think the cause of the CoreData warning is with this line of code:

```
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

You are accessing the `viewContext` before the store is loaded. Try moving that line inside the load persistent store completion block:

```
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
})
```

Comment: Now that warning has been gone,But when i check the sqllite file the data is showing me empty.

Comment: Did you try setting a break-point on your saveContext method and checking that context.hasChanges is true? I can only guess that you are maybe not saving the context where you created the new objects?

Comment: The context.hasChanges is being returning true

Comment: Context changes : true
Context objects : [<BoardEntity: 0x607000165170> (entity: Board; id: 0x6030001a27b0 <x-coredata:///Board/t00E8F796-69DC-48B2-B26F-CF51A0C1D3AE2> ; data: {...set the values...}

Comment: Try enabling SQL Debugging so you can see what the save is doing. Add the following as a launch argument in the scheme editor: -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 (don't forget the leading "-").

Comment: I have attached the screen-shot

Comment: Did you enable the debugging? If you have new managed objects in the context you are saving you should see an INSERT statement for each object. If not something is wrong with the way you create the managed objects. Difficult to say what unless you share some of that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157759/discussion-between-joe-and-kharrison).

Comment: fixed the issue, Thanks for the help.